# Hover Animation won't disappear when not hovering

Tags: html, css, animation

I have a div I've animated on hover. However when I am not hovering the div won't disappear

This is what the entire thing looks like in action: http://jsfiddle.net/Vbxtc/

This is the html:

```
    <nav>
       <div id="controls">
            <button id="playButton">Play</button>      
            <div id="defaultBar">
                <div id="progressBar"></div>
            </div>
            <button id="vol" onclick="level()">Vol</button>
            <button id="mute">Mute</button>
            <button id="full" onclick="toggleFullScreen()">Full</button>
        </div> 
       <div id="playlist" class="animated fadeInRight">
            <div>cats</div>
            <div>cats</div>
            <div>cats</div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

This is the CSS i've made:

```
#playlist{
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    border:1px solid red;
    height: 82%;
    width: 25%;
    top: 20px;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: 2;
    float:right;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px; 
    color:white;
    background-color:#999999;
    opacity: 0;
}
#playlist:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

This is the animation im trying

```
.animated:hover {
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -ms-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
    -ms-animation-duration: 1s;
    -o-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}

.fadeInRight {
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInRight;
    -moz-animation-name: fadeInRight;
    -o-animation-name: fadeInRight;
    animation-name: fadeInRight;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeOutRight {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(20px);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInRight {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(20px);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hovering upon which item does it not disappear? Is it the hovering in the whitespace to the left?

Comment: Yea when I go the left side of the white space. The div will animate and opacity will go to 1. If I let the animation finish, then move my mouse outside the area. The div does not leave (opacity 0)

Comment: If you are referring to all the divs like the "cats cats" and "play vol mut full" then I find it gets disappeared when mouse moved out. Which browser are you using?

Comment: The one with Cats. The bottom controls are doing what they are suppose to. Im using Chrome.

Comment: Oh so then you have to make an edit to your question as it would be related to changing code for multiple browser functionality, because you can try using it in the latest firefox and it works.

Comment: I think I figured it out. I added :hover to .fadeInRight and it seems to work. The div with cats in it. THe problem was if you left ur mouse long enough (gave the animation time to finish). Once you removed your mouse the div didn't disappear (it's suppose to). But yea not it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that when you time the mouse over exactly right (hover for about 1 second and move mouse up top), it DOES fade out nicely.

The other thing is, if you add the class fadeOutRight as follows:

```
<div id="playlist" class="animated fadeInRight fadeOutRight">
```

It fades out too quickly.

I know I didn't help much but the answer lies in the timing.

Also, if you had the fadeOutRight class on, for example, the sidebar, it works nicely!

```
<aside id="sidebar" class="fadeOutRight">
```

Perhaps, put the class of fadeOutRight on everything EXCEPT the fadeInRight div.

Comment: Still, if you mouse over for too long, the div remains.  The answer has to do with the timing.  Hope this helps somehow!

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to play with an element position in the hover state.
Even if you get to program it right (that is not easy), most of the time the user won't understand what's happening.

You can get flickering scenarios where, without the user moving the cursor, your div leaves the cursor position, canceling the hover, the div re-entering the cursor, the hover triggering , and so on.

I would recomend to trigger the hover on another div that covers the full area where the moving div will be.

Comment: I ended up figuring out the problem. It works pretty well but I am missing something to indicate to the user that this area contains a playlist, not sure what though. See here: http://www3.carleton.ca/clubs/sissa/html5/video.html